QGIS crashing when running Raster/Extraction/Contour
Why is QGIS 3.40.2 crashing when I Run Raster/Extraction/Contour?
The reason for crash in the report is "Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process:   QGIS [55535]
The file input for the extraction is a LiDAR DTM GeoTIFF.
Computer: Model: MacBookPro18,3, BootROM 11881.41.5, proc 8:6:2 processors, 16 GB, SMC
Graphics: Apple M1 Pro, Apple M1 Pro, Built-In; OS Sonoma 14.7.1.
Full crash report available at :  https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/r58ygv223s4usfji9l8j0/Contour-crash-report.pdf?rlkey=0ki1qlo2q4lni9ofx1vf0t61n&dl=0
Layer/properties/information, below:
General
Name    LiDAR Culbin extension Merged file
Path    /Users/michaelsharpe/Documents/Science and Technology/ARCHAEOLOGY/Scotland/Moray/Findhorn Dunes Site/Maps, mine/FDsites QGIS map/LiDAR processing only/LiDAR Culbin extension Merged file.tif
Sidecar file    LiDAR Culbin extension Merged file.tif.aux.xml
Total size  2.76 GB
Last modified   29 December 2024 14:36:29 GMT (LiDAR Culbin extension Merged file.tif.aux.xml)
Provider    gdal
Information from provider
Extent  280000.0000000000000000,850000.0041000000201166 : 317000.0000000000000000,870000.0041000000201166
Width   37000
Height  20000
Data type   Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point
GDAL Driver Description GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata    GeoTIFF
Dataset Description /Users/michaelsharpe/Documents/Science and Technology/ARCHAEOLOGY/Scotland/Moray/Findhorn Dunes Site/Maps, mine/FDsites QGIS map/LiDAR processing only/LiDAR Culbin extension Merged file.tif
Compression
Band 1
STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=218.2440032959
STATISTICS_MEAN=12.718521019414
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-2.3199999332428
STATISTICS_STDDEV=30.312670062652
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Scale: 1
Offset: 0
More information
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Dimensions  X: 37000 Y: 20000 Bands: 1
Origin  280000.0000000000000000,870000.0041000000201166
Pixel Size  1,-1
Coordinate Reference System (CRS)
Name    EPSG:27700 - OSGB36 / British National Grid
Units   meters
Type    Projected
Method  Transverse Mercator
Celestial Body  Earth
Reference   Static (relies on a datum which is plate-fixed)
Identification
Identifier
Parent Identifier
Title
Type    dataset
Language
Abstract
Categories
Keywords
Extent
CRS British_National_Grid - Projected
Spatial Extent
Temporal Extent
Access
Fees
Licenses
Rights
Constraints
Bands
Band count  1
Number  Band    NoData  Min Max
1   Band 1  n/a -2.3199999332   218.2440032959
Contacts
No contact yet.
References
No links yet.
History
No history yet.


Please provide all the parameters set for the Raster/Extraction/Contour tool.

OK, I have added a screen grab of the Contour parameters.  I should have mentioned that the process did run for 10–15 minutes and created three output files (*GPKG), but then crashed.

You are trying to create a 0.5 m interval contour layer on a raster layer having an extent of 37 Km x 20 Km at 1 m per pixel resolution. I guess the GDAL tool makes QGIS crash due to hitting some memory limit. Have you tried if the crash also occurs even setting a greater interval value (e.g. 10 or 100) and / or using a raster layer with a smaller extent or a smaller resolution? Have you tried with a different output layer format (e.g. ESRI Shapefile)? May you provide the raster layer?

Another possible cause of the issue may be the fact that the GDAL/OGR library version used by QGIS on your system is not up-to-date.
Some alternative QGIS installation methods for macOS, shipping up-to-date version of the GDAL/OGR library, are e.g. MacPorts https://qgis.org/resources/installation-guide/#macports and Conda forge https://aneto.pt/posts/tutorials/2019-05-29-using-qgis-from-conda/
